# Troubles sharing specific content on Linkedin

Tags: redirect, linkedin-api, share

Our site datahub.ren.pt has a sharing feature on Linkedin.

However, when we share from the website for this type of URL (a graphic) it gives an error: https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=https%3a%2f%2fdatahub.ren.pt%3a443 %2fpt%2feletricidade%2fbalanco-dario%2fmodules%2fconsumption-toggle%2fdetailed%2fdetailed%2f%3fdate%3d2023-07-27

If we share it, for example, on Facebook, there is no problem: https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fdatahub.ren.pt%3A443%2Fpt%2Feletricidade%2Fbalanco -diary%2Fmodules%2Ftoggle%2Fdetailed%2Fdetailed%2F%3Fdate%3D2023-07-27

If done from any other site page, it shares correctly.

We used Post Inspector from linkedin and it gives back two errors: 302 redirect and 303 redirect.

Using inspector in the browser we get:
9vghoawmkb5fvzav7oabel24l:2393  Error while processing route: inshare.index Ember Data Request GET /voyager/api/contentcreation/urlPreview [inshare-common/routes/index]